# Is it possible to use curl/json with tcl and retrieve spotify API data?

Tags: api, tcl, spotify

I'm trying to make a simple proc in TCL that gets data from SPOTIFY API about what track I'm currently playing.

Any ideas are welcome. :D

Format:
`GET https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/currently-playing`

I need to send this:

```
curl -X "GET" "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/currently-playing?market=ES&additional_types=episode" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer BQAai*****8n-5zXrLypj********hsgafd"
```

(*id code for auth masked*)

Reference: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/

Comment: There's a library that lets you use libcurl directly from tcl if you don't want to exec an external program. And tcllib has a json parsing library for making sense of the results of that request.

Comment: I recommend the [rl_json](https://github.com/RubyLane/rl_json) package.

Comment: Many thanks! Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a variant of Donald's solution using Tcl's built-in http support:

```
package require http; 
package require json;

package require tls
::http::register https 443 ::tls::socket

set spotifyToken "BQAai*****8n-5zXrLypj********hsgafd"

proc spotifyGet {api args} {
  global spotifyToken;
  set url https://api.spotify.com/v1/$api?[http::formatQuery {*}$args]

  dict set hdrs Authorization [list Bearer $spotifyToken]
  dict set hdrs Accept "application/json"

  set token [http::geturl $url \
                 -type "application/json" \
                 -headers $hdrs]

  if {[http::status $token] eq "ok"} {
    set responseBody [http::data $token]
  } else {
    error "Spotify call failed: [http::error $token]"
  }

  http::cleanup $token
  return [json::json2dict $responseBody]
}

set data [spotifyGet me/player/currently-playing market ES additional_types episode]
```

Not so complicated, after all, but requires an additional dependency: [TclTLS](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/tls).

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

As a first cut, here's a very simple wrapper:

```
proc curl args {
    # The options skip showing stuff you don't want in scripted form
    # They also enable following redirects; you probably want to do that!
    exec curl -s -S -L {*}$args
}

# Usually easiest to keep this sort of thing separate
set spotifyToken "BQAai*****8n-5zXrLypj********hsgafd"

# -G to force the use of the GET verb
set json [curl -G "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/currently-playing?market=ES&additional_types=episode" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer $spotifyToken"]
```

We can wrap that further:

```
package require http;  # Standard part of Tcl
package require json;  # Part of tcllib

proc spotifyGet {api args} {
    global spotifyToken; # Assume variable set as earlier
    set url https://api.spotify.com/v1/$api?[http::formatQuery {*}$args]
    set options {-H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json"}
    lappend options -H "Authorization: Bearer $spotifyToken"
    return [json::json2dict [curl -G $url {*}$options]]
}

set data [spotifyGet me/player/currently-playing market ES additional_types episode]
puts [dict get $data item name]
```

If you're doing more serious JSON work, consider using the `rl_json` library. And you'll need to explore the data you get back to understand it. (I can't test; I don't use Spotify.)

Comment: You might also be able to make the call with the Tcl built-in http library, but that's rather lower level than cURL.